# Infinite Scroll for Polymer 1.0 (without appending)

Tags: scroll, polymer, infinite

Tried mixing some jQuery but everything is based on appending, something I don't wanna use because i'm trying to base my design completely on binding and stamping templates and elements. I tried using scrollTop in various ways but I always ended up being depended on what's appended on the local DOM. If i'm not mistaken, dom-repeat has nothing to do with appending, but with creating the same stamp and bind it multiple times (correct me if i'm wrong, I started looking into Polymer 1 recently).

I only found this one good example of using infinite scroll over a repeating template https://github.com/chadliu23/event-infinite-scroll but unfortunately it's not what i'm looking for as I'm mixing iron-ajax parsing data into my template. Simulating chadliu23's example lead me into a silly middle step of creating an extra array and pushing data from ajax into it, but it is totally something I don't want to do cause it's messing with my repeatable template restamping.
Also realized that there are ways to create infinite scrolling-ish effects with css but can't figure out any other way to implement this but in sets of images.

Meanwhile, sadly, it seems like iron-list is nowhere near ready yet and I can't find any way to use the concept idea of core-list into polymer 1.0.

So..... Any suggestions on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an `item-page` component:

```
<dom-module id="item-page">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax id="ajax"
      params="{{_composeParamsForPage(page)}}"
      last-response="{{pageData}}">
    </iron-ajax>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{pageData}}" as="item">
      <!-- Compose your list of items for this page here -->
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function(){
      "use strict";

      Polymer({
        is: 'item-page',
        properties: {
          page: {
            type: Number,
            observer: '_updatePage(page)'
          }
        },
        _updatePage: function(page) {
          this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Then, to create an infinitely scrolling list:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{pages}}" as="page">
  <item-page page="{{page}}"></item-page>
</template>
```

It's important that in your `item-page` component the `iron-ajax` does *not* have `auto` set, because the `page` property will initially be set to `undefined`.  Instead, you should observe `page` and act accordingly only once it's updated to something other than `undefined`.

Comment: So if I understood correctly the idea is based on toggling the loading mode depending the scrollTop position(this is gonna be interesting)? Also, -my brain has been turning into stew for a few hours so here's a derp question-: What kind of property is pages - any extra info about it?

Comment: `loading` will take care of itself, all you should have to manage is the `pages` array, which will contain the page numbers to load.  When you are ready to load the next page, just use `this.push('pages', <pagenum>)` to append a new page number to the end of the array. Polymer is observing the `pages` array and will automatically stamp the `dom-repeat` contents for that page, which will include a new `iron-ajax`.

Comment: Since `pages` is an array it's important that you use Polymer's `this.push` to append to it, else Polymer won't know that `pages` was updated.  `pages` could also conceivably have any page numbers you like, so your infinite scroll could start at page 1 or page 50.

Comment: Sounds amazing, will get back to you once I've tried it. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: On review I think I may be mistaken on one point: `pageData` will keep the same scope at every iteration through the `pages` loop, meaning every time a new page is loaded it'll go back and restamp all the old pages with the new data! I'm not sure how to "re-scope" a bound variable, but I'm looking into that now.

Comment: After banging my head against it for a bit I think the only viable solution would be to create a second component, but the good news is that it would be reusable in a variety of situations.  I'll update my answer with a mockup.

Comment: I see, so dynamically handling the ajax requests as _updatePage gets activated. This is a pretty awesome idea :D